# what is wrong in this code? I have to use a volatile pointer to union, which gives error in operator overloading =

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

constvolatile.cpp:91:9: error: passing âvolatile GENERIC_COMMANDâ as âthisâ argument of âconst GENERIC_COMMAND& GENERIC_COMMAND::operator=(const T&) [with T = COMPLETION_WAIT, GENERIC_COMMAND = GENERIC_COMMAND]â discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

```
            #include <iostream>
            using namespace std;

             typedef unsigned int uint32_t;
             typedef unsigned long long  uint64_t;

               union GENERIC_COMMAND
                {
                    struct
                    {
                        uint64_t first_operand  :   60;
                        uint64_t opcode         :   4;
                        uint64_t second_operand :   64;
                    };

                    struct
                    {
                        uint32_t dword1;
                        uint32_t dword2;
                        uint32_t dword3;
                        uint32_t dword4;
                    };

                    struct
                    {
                        uint64_t qword1;
                        uint64_t qword2;
                    };

                    GENERIC_COMMAND() {
                    }
                    GENERIC_COMMAND(volatile const GENERIC_COMMAND&){}

                    template <typename T>
                    volatile GENERIC_COMMAND& operator=(const T& rhs) volatile
                    {
                        this->dword1 = rhs.dword1;
                        this->dword2 = rhs.dword2;
                        this->dword3 = rhs.dword3;
                        this->dword4 = rhs.dword4;
                        return *this;
                    }
                };


             union COMPLETION_WAIT
                {
                    struct
                    {
                        uint64_t s              :   1;
                        uint64_t i              :   1;
                        uint64_t f              :   1;
                        uint64_t store_address  :   49;
                        uint64_t reserved1      :   8;
                        uint64_t opcode         :   4;
                        uint64_t store_data     :   64;
                    };
                    struct
                    {
                        uint32_t dword1;
                        uint32_t dword2;
                        uint32_t dword3;
                        uint32_t dword4;
                    };
                };


             void add_completion_wait_command(uint32_t s, uint32_t i, uint32_t f,
                                    uint64_t store_address, uint64_t store_data,
                                    bool auto_flush)
                {
                    COMPLETION_WAIT command;
                    command.dword1 = 0;     
                    command.dword2 = 0;    
                    command.dword3 = 0;    
                    command.dword4 = 0;     

                    command.s = s;
                    command.i = i;
                    command.f = f;
                    command.store_address = store_address >> 3;
                    command.opcode = 0x1;
                    command.store_data = store_data;

                    GENERIC_COMMAND generic;
                    static_cast<GENERIC_COMMAND>(generic = command);

                }

            main()
            {
                    cout<< "in main"<< endl;
                    volatile GENERIC_COMMAND* A;//this has to be volatile only.
                    COMPLETION_WAIT cw;
                    A = new volatile union GENERIC_COMMAND;
                    static_cast<GENERIC_COMMAND>(A[0] = cw);

            }
```

Comment: Just to be clear: you say you have a "volatile pointer", but in your code you have a pointer *to a volatile object*. Which one do you want?

Comment: @jrok yes it is pointer to a volatile object.

Answer (score 3):

Your operator= needs to be volatile. Just as a member function needs to be const to be invoked on a const object. If your member function is not volatile, the compiler would optimize its body, which is not what you want for a volatile object. So the language has this useful rule.

It is well known that this error happens even with the implicitly declared operator=, and is documented as one of the incompatibilities to the C language.

EDIT: I would like to mention that the object you assign to is not volatile, so a compiler is free to optimize away operations on it, even if the pointer used to access it has the volatile qualifier. Add volatile to the type of it

```
new volatile union GENERIC_COMMAND
```

Comment: making operator= volatile is not working out. declaration in code makes a[0] volatile (object), in constructor const is reference to object.

Comment: could resolve "warning: implicit dereference will not access object of type volatile GENERIC_COMMAND in statement" with static_cast and copy constructor.